# SKPhysicsContactDelegate didBegin won't run

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I was creating a Swift Playground using SpriteKit but couldn't get collision detection to work. I've read all of the posts regarding this issue on StackOverFlow and none of them has solved my issues. Below is my code:

```
public class MyScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {    

var node: SKSpriteNode?

var touchedNodeCreator: Timer?

let nodeCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1

let touchedNodeCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2

var score = 0

public override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    //Setup

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    self.backgroundColor =
        UIColor(red:0.60, green:0.88, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)

    //node

    node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "node")

    node!.setScale(0.175)

    node!.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: node!.size)

    node!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = nodeCategory

    node!.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = touchedNodeCategory

    node!.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = floorCategory

    floor.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = floorCategory

    floor.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = nodeCategory

    let nodeStartingPos = CGPoint(x: node!.size.width / 2 + 25, y: self.size.height / 5 + node!.size.height / 2)

    node!.position = nodeStartingPos

    addChild(node!)

    //Create touchedNode Timer

    touchedNodeCreator = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true) { (timer) in
        self.createtouchedNode()
    }

}

func createtouchedNode() {

    let touchedNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "otherNode")

    touchedNode.setScale(0.2)

    touchedNode.name = "TouchedNode"

    touchedNode.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: touchedNode.size)

    touchedNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    let maxY = self.size.height / 1 - touchedNode.size.height / 2

    let minY = self.size.height / 5 + 25

    let rangeY = maxY - minY

    let y = maxY - CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(rangeY)))

    let touchedNodeStartingPos = CGPoint(x: self.size.width + 20, y: y)

    touchedNode.position = touchedNodeStartingPos

    touchedNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = touchedNodeCategory

    touchedNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = nodeCategory

    addChild(touchedNode)

    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -size.width - touchedNode.size.width, y: 0, duration: 3)

    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveLeft, remove])

    touchedNode.run(sequence)

}

public func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    print("Began")

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == touchedNodeCategory {

        contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()

        score += 1

        print(score)

    } else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == touchedNodeCategory {

        contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()

        score += 1

        print(score)

    }

}
```

Please keep in mind that I have omitted a lot of code, mainly just code that moves the node when any touch is detected.

I would appreciate it if you guys could help me get this solved. Thanks!

Comment: have you assigned the SKPhysicsContactDelegate to the gameScene class?

`class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot to add that in the code

Comment: Yes, I have assigned that already, it still doesn’t work.

Comment: You probably removed code for other nodes, then we are unable to be certain that masks are correctly set...

Comment: Most of the code that I removed was code to detect touch and move the node. I didn’t remove any mask code.